# How to use 'groupBy' method on a list of Int, & Strings

Tags: scala

I managed to group a List of Strings by length:

```
List("Every", "student", "likes", "Scala").groupBy((element: String) => element.length)
```

I want to group a tuple (i.e),

```
("Every", "student", "likes", "Scala", 1, 5, 54, 0, 1, 0)
```

Comment: In your tuple, what do you want to do about the Ints, do you want to filter them out ?

Comment: Add more information to the question. What is the expected result?

Comment: @MaheshChand wanted a  `Map` senario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `groupBy` method takes a predicate function as its parameter and uses it to group elements by key and values into a Map collection.

As per the Scala documentation, the definition of the groupBy method is as follows:

```
groupBy[K](f: (A) ⇒ K): immutable.Map[K, Repr]
```

Hence assuming that you have a tuple of Int and String and you want to groupBy Strings, I would perform the following steps

```
1. Create a list from tuple
2. Filter out types other than String
3. Apply groupBy on the list
```

The code for this as follows :-

```
("Every", "student", "likes", "Scala", 1, 5, 54, 0, 1, 0)
  .productIterator.toList
  .filter(_.isInstanceOf[String])
  .map(_.asInstanceOf[String])
  .groupBy((element: String) => element.length)
```